# Как изменить базовую директорию на странице?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Изменение базовой директории работает только без слеша. Если указан слеш к примеру перед ссылкой то не работает. Есть решения этой проблемы на уровне htaccess?
Ниже приведу примеры:

htaccess:

> RewriteBase /folder/

```
 <a href="restore" >1</a> - http://example.com/folder/restore
 <a href="/restore">2</a> - http://example.com/restore
 <a href="/">3</a>        - http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

зависит от того site.ru/ или site.ru

Если сайт на CMS - можно посмотреть настройки.
и страницы склейте чтобы site.ru/about/ и site.ru/about было одно и то же